# Product Gallery doesn't allow grabbing to scroll images on Mobile after upgrade

Tags: product, gallery, magento2.4.6

Following the implementation of the latest upgrade onto our site, we've observed that in mobile viewpoints, the product image gallery doesn't allow for the user to scroll between images/videoes via grabbing, it only works using the dots at the bottom. Has anyone been able to find a fix for this?

I also noticed this has happened to the Magento 2 Store galleries as well so its clearly something that the latest upgrade has caused as our testing site is still on 2.4.5 and the gallery still works in mobile view

Answer (score 2):

We recently upgraded from Magento 2.4.4 to 2.4.6 and have the same issue.

It has been reported & confirmed at Magento GitHub:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/37232

The fix that worked for me is editing lib/web/fotorama/fotorama.js line 1143

```
- el.addEventListener ? el.addEventListener(e, fn, !!bool) : el.attachEvent('on' + e, fn);
+ const options = {
+  get passive() {
+   return e === 'wheel';
+  }
+ }
+ el.addEventListener ? el.addEventListener(e, fn, options) : el.attachEvent('on' + e, fn);
```

Solution on GitHub:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/37232#issuecomment-1517467878

Comment: This one worked for me.